# Ajax image upload

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, upload

I have a form where I do a ajax image upload triggered on onChange event for the input element (file). The ajax image upload works fine but I notice that the image is uploaded again on submitting the form itself. How can I prevent the image from being uploaded again?

Comment: make your button not to upload the file?

Comment: Code, please!  Is this something you downloaded or something you invented?

Comment: I am using the code posted  http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/thumbnail-image-upload-ajaxphp/

Answer (score 1):

If the file `input` is being handled separately than the form (with an AJAX call) and shouldn't be part of the form, move it outside of the `form` tag.  This will likely affect your page layout, so you may want to make some style changes.  But think of it from the perspective of just looking at the HTML markup.  Elements which aren't part of parent elements shouldn't be nested within those parent elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the `submit` event for the form and clear the value of the file input so that it is blank when the form submits:

```
$('#your-form-id').on('submit', function () {
    $('#your-file-input').val('');
    return true;
});
```

You can also move the file input outside the rest of the form, so there will be two form tags but you can use `position : absolute;` to position the file input to appear as though it is inside the other form.

Comment: Would it work if I wrap the file input tag in a form and nest it within the other form? I guess I will have to try that

Comment: Since I don't know the structure of your HTML I made a simple example of my second suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/c3M6W/

Answer (score 0):

I  think you have to submit the form using javascript in onchange event

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, form action should be empty:

```
<form action="">
```

In JS code use:

```
$('#submut').click(function(){
    var //get var by jQuery
});
//Your $ajax code here...
```